# How to make an HTTP request using a custom verb?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

In order to test an API, I want to be able to make HTTP requests using custom verbs (such as "RECOMPUTE")¹, other than GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, TRACE and CONNECT.

Is there a library which already does that, or do I have to reinvent the wheel using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`?

Answers to [another, less specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917290/240613), suggest several libraries, none being compatible with what I need:

- WebClient doesn't support custom verbs,
- EasyHttp is limited to five verbs,
- HttpClient seems not maintained (version 0.6.0, released two years ago).

---

<sup>¹ In anticipation of comments such as "Using non-standard verbs is a bad idea", there is nothing I can do with that. I'm using a private API where the choice was made to use custom verbs.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class in .NET 4.5. Not only does it support the common ones, but it allows you to specify your own method as well.

Construct your own verb by using the `HttpMethod` class.

```
var method = new HttpMethod("RECOMPUTE");
```

Docs:

- [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159066%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [HttpMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)