# Calling asp.net 4.5 web service returns 302 and redirects to default page

Tags: asp.net, web-services

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: url,
    data: dataParameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        //
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //
    }
});
```

when using this in my local everything is fine but on host its return

```
[HTTP/1.1 302 Found 278ms]
```

my WS function :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SomeFunction(int something) {
    //          
}
```

Comment: Does your host have any filter for http requests ? (headers or something else you wouldn't send here)

Comment: @cubitouch : I don't know. its plesk control panel. where is it?

Comment: I do not know this control panel, can you try to add a route in your web service and simulate an http request to your webservice target to see if the result is the same ? (in order to identify is the 'client side' is blocking in some way)

Comment: @cubitouch : we already use asp.net route in our app. can you explain your solution a bit more with some sample?

Comment: Just declare a route B (SomeFunctionTester route) which will try an HTTP request to the route A (SomeFunction route). From Server to Server, juste to see if it works without client side. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917290/making-and-receiving-an-http-request-in-c-sharp)

Comment: its return same error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44692/discussion-between-cubitouch-and-raika)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route was my problem. adding this line to route solve my problem :

```
routes.Ignore("{*allasmx}", new { allasmx = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: You can flag your own anwser as a solution if it solved your issue ;)

Comment: yeah i know but its say i can do it tomorrow :)